# Removing shadows from an object, not the shadow being casted

Tags: rendering, shaders, shadows, workbench-render-engine

I've got a model that looks best when rendered through the Workbench render engine, but for a specific scene I would like it to still be able to cast shadows. Is there a certain way for the model to cast a shadow without the light affecting them, keeping it in a Workbench-esque render?

[image]

Comment: You could use the header menu > View > Viewport Render Animation function. Or use an Emission shader rather than Diffuse?